# How can I set background color for full height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have created hexagons, now I want to set their background color to -> #1B2435. Because my web page background color is that. But when I set this background color I can see white spaces on my web page. Can not make all of them bg color.

This is my react file

```
import React from "react";
import "./Hexagon.css";

const Hexagon = () => {
  return (
    <div className="h-full xl:h-[calc(100vh-84px)] bg-transparent">
      <ul className="honeycomb bg-transparent">
        <li className="honeycomb-cell">
          <img className="honeycomb-cell_image" src="" />
          <div className="honeycomb-cell_title">FullDOSER</div>
        </li>
        <li className="honeycomb-cell">
          <img className="honeycomb-cell_image" src="" />
          <div className="honeycomb-cell_title">LowDOSER</div>
        </li>
        <li className="honeycomb-cell">
          <img className="honeycomb-cell_image" src="" />
          <div className="honeycomb-cell_title">TrenDOSER</div>
        </li>
        <li className="honeycomb-cell">
          <img className="honeycomb-cell_image" src="" />
          <div className="honeycomb-cell_title">HostDOSER</div>
        </li>
        <li className="honeycomb-cell">
          <img className="honeycomb-cell_image" src="" />
          <div className="honeycomb-cell_title">DeepDOSER</div>
        </li>
        <li className="honeycomb-cell">
          <img className="honeycomb-cell_image" src="" />
          <div className="honeycomb-cell_title">CustomDOSER</div>
        </li>
        <li className="honeycomb-cell bg-backgroundColor w-full">
          <img className="honeycomb-cell_image" src="" />
          <div className="honeycomb-cell_title">MagicDOSER</div>
        </li>
        <li className="honeycomb-cell honeycomb_placeholder honeycomb_Hidden bg-backgroundColor"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hexagon;
```

This is my css file

```
.honeycomb {
  background: transparent;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateY(80px);
}

.honeycomb-cell {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 1 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 137.5px;
  margin: 65.4px 12.5px 25px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #000;
}
.honeycomb-cell_img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.honeycomb-cell_title {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
  color: #09a781;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  transition: opacity 350ms;
}
.honeycomb-cell_title > small {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.honeycomb-cell::before,
.honeycomb-cell::after {
  content: "";
}
.honeycomb-cell::before,
.honeycomb-cell::after,
.honeycomb-cell_img {
  top: -50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    50% 0%,
    100% 25%,
    100% 75%,
    50% 100%,
    0% 75%,
    0% 25%
  );
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.honeycomb-cell::before {
  background: #000;
  transform: scale(1.055);
}
.honeycomb-cell::after {
  background: #111111;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity 350ms;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 350ms;
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover .honeycomb-cell_title {
  opacity: 100;
  color: #fff;
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover .honeycomb-cell_img {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover::before {
  background: #312d4b;
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.honeycomb_Hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 12.5px;
}

/****** Responsive *******/

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .honeycomb-cell {
    margin: 81.25px 25px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 825px) {
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: calc(50% - 125px);
    margin-left: calc(50% - 125px);
  }

  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(3n + 5) {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 825px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(5n + 4) {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 275px);
  }

  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(5n + 5) {
    margin-right: calc(50% - 275px);
  }

  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(5n),
  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(5n + 3) {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(7n + 5) {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 400px);
  }

  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(7n + 7),
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(7n + 5):nth-last-child(2) {
    margin-right: calc(50% - 400px);
  }

  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(7n + 7),
  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(7n + 9),
  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(7n + 11) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

React code

```
    import React from "react";
import Hexagon from "../components/scanComponents/Hexagon";

const ScanPackage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="">
        {/* Header */}
        <div className="w-full text-textColor -mb-10">
          <div className="flex items-center mb-4">
            <hr className="w-full hidden md:block" />
            <div className="text-center text-2xl w-full">Scan Packages</div>
            <hr className="w-full hidden md:block" />
          </div>

          <div className="w-full sm:w-[60%] text-center text-sm md:text-base mx-auto">
            Test Test <hr className="mt-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Body */}
      <Hexagon />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScanPackage;
```

I have tried to set all of my honeycomb background color to transparent and give main page background color. But it also didn't take all of it on tablet and mobile screen. On desktop screen it's working without any problem. How can I fix this problem ?

[image: Hexagon screenshot on mobile screen]

Comment: I imitated it in codepen and works fine without white spaces, https://codepen.io/junaidcody/pen/GRXraKJ , if it occurs in your page then it must be some other component altering the html

Comment: I have added my react code also. There is menu and sidebar. I have created route path for getting this page. Sidebar is fixed but menu is not. I have deleted both of them to check if error gone or not. And delete them didn't solve anything

Comment: Can you make the resultant HTML and CSS into a runnable snippet which definitely shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this because of `margin: 65.4px 12.5px 25px;` in `.honeycomb-cell`.

I suggest you completely use `tailwind-css` instead of mixing it with pure css.

Strategy to follow:

```
<div class="min-h-screen bg-[#1B2435]">  min-h-screen should serve your purpose
  <ul class="">
    <li></li>
    ...
    <li></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

As your custom classes are having margin, you are not able to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: I have set it like that, but nothing changed at all. Also I can not figure out how to change my -webkit to tailwind so I just used pure css file. I just deleted this margins but again I see this white screen

Comment: Then i guess only for the webkit part you can use custom css, and for the rest use tailwind-css and try to edit the question, I might be of some help, but be aware of usage of margin, because that is causing the undesired behaviour

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can help me, thank you for that :)

Comment: Removing the margin is getting rid of the whitespace in the bottom, but that would distort the orientation of the hexagon, i will be happy to assist you further